# Get xml Attributes to arrays c# Windows form

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

Just wanted to get values from XML file of an particular attribute to store in array.
So far I did this, but it didn't make out.

C# Code

```
string[] name;
int n = 0;
using (XmlTextReader AReader = new XmlTextReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Account.xml"))
        {
            while (AReader.Read())
            {
                AReader.ReadToFollowing("Account");
                AReader.MoveToContent();
                if (AReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && AReader.Name == "Account")
                {
                    name[n] = AReader.GetAttribute("Name");
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ArrayOfAccount>
   <Account Name="John" Sex="Male" Age="28" />
   <Account Name="Ram" Sex="Male" Age="22" />
 </ArrayOfAccount>
```

What output I need is

```
name[0]="John"
name[1]="Ram"
```

and So on...

I think this is enough to get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `List<T>`, not an array. Arrays have a fixed size, which must be known beforehand, while lists can grow, making them ideal for this kind of application.

So, first off, create a new list:

```
var name = new List<string>();
// no need for n, the list keeps track of its count
```

Then, add elements to it:

```
if (AReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && AReader.Name == "Account")
{
    name.Add(AReader.GetAttribute("Name"));
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: It worked fine. but when I try to get output from for loop it wasn't getting maybe I did something wrong or not, but foreach loop helped me to get the output. Appreciated Man!

Answer (score -1):

You can get using linq. By this no need to bother about size and you get string[] array.

Complete Code

```
 string myXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                          <ArrayOfAccount>
                         <Account Name=""John"" Sex =""Male"" Age=""28""/>
                         <Account Name=""Ram"" Sex=""Male"" Age=""22""/>
                         </ArrayOfAccount>
                         ";

            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
            xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);

            IEnumerable<string> names = (from account in
                                          xdoc.Descendants("Account")
                                        select account.Attribute("Name").Value).ToArray();
```

in Your case , it is file  so

```
IEnumerable<string> names = (from account in
                                    XDocument.Load(@"yourPath")
                                              .Descendants("Account")
                                        select customers.Attribute("Name").Value).ToArray();
```

[image]

Comment: The OP shows complete code reading the file - so should you.

Comment: I am new here what is OP?

Comment: Original Poster - the guy that asked the question.

Comment: @pradeep Kumar, Even it worked, but  List<T> is more efficient to use the result again for any reason, But it worked completely fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity Please find complete code.

Comment: `XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(); xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);` - really?

Comment: I  just used to create demo so can show how code works.

Comment: what should i use instead of Parse?

Comment: The OP is loading from a file. Your code is parsing from a string. There's no need to do something different. Make your answer match the OP's question. Also, calling `new XDocument()` and then throwing away the new instance is a waste.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the easy way to do what you want:

```
string[] name =
    XDocument
        .Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Account.xml")
        .Root
        .Elements("Account")
        .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("Name"))
        .ToArray();
```